# Qt UI freezes when GL update greater 15 Hz

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, opengl

I have a Qt application with worker thread. The worker thread executes 2 functions `void cWorker::updDynamics()` and `void cWorker::updGraphics()` at different frequencies using 2 `QTimer`.

`updGraphics()` connects to a slot in a `class GLWidget : public QGLWidget` in the main thread, which simply invokes `updateGL();`

My problem is that my main window freezes (GL widget gets updated but I can't resize the window or click buttons) if my graphics update rate is > 15 Hz. Why is this happening and how can I avoid this problem? - I'd like to get 50Hz update at least.

```
cWorker::cWorker()
{
    m_vertex = 0.1;    
}

void cWorker::init()
{
    int upd_rate_dynamics = 1000; //Hz
    int upd_rate_graphics = 15; //Hz

    m_timer_dynamics = new QTimer(this);
    connect(m_timer_dynamics, SIGNAL( timeout() ), this, SLOT( updDynamics() ));
    m_timer_dynamics->start(1000.0/upd_rate_dynamics);

    m_timer_graphics = new QTimer(this);
    connect(m_timer_graphics, SIGNAL( timeout() ), this, SLOT( updGraphics() ));
    m_timer_graphics->start(1000.0/upd_rate_graphics);
}

void cWorker::updDynamics()
{
    std::cout << "cWorker::updDynamics()" << std::endl;
    m_vertex += 0.0005;
}

void cWorker::updGraphics()
{
    std::cout << "cWorker::updGraphics()" << std::endl;
    emit requestRepaint();
}



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    cWorker* worker = new cWorker();
    QThread* thread = new QThread;
    worker->moveToThread(thread);

    QObject::connect(thread, SIGNAL(started()), worker, SLOT(init()) );
    thread->start();

    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;

    GLWidget *my_gl_widget = w.findChild<GLWidget*>("widget");
    my_gl_widget->m_worker_ptr = worker;

    QObject::connect(worker, SIGNAL( requestRepaint() ), my_gl_widget, SLOT( receiveRepaint() ));

    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the documentation [QTimer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtimer.html).
Especially this part:

> In multithreaded applications, you can use QTimer in any thread that has an event loop. To start an event loop from a non-GUI thread, use QThread::exec(). Qt uses the timer's thread affinity to determine which thread will emit the timeout() signal. Because of this, you must start and stop the timer in its thread; it is not possible to start a timer from another thread.

And this:

> From then on, processOneThing() will be called repeatedly. It should be written in such a way that it always returns quickly (typically after processing one data item) so that Qt can deliver events to the user interface and stop the timer as soon as it has done all its work. This is the traditional way of implementing heavy work in GUI applications, but as multithreading is nowadays becoming available on more and more platforms, we expect that zero-millisecond QTimers will gradually be replaced by QThreads.

Comment: But I am creating and starting the timers in the worker thread, in `void cWorker::init()`. I don't understand what to do differently. Are you saying I shouldn't use timers at all? Can you give a code example? Where should I call `QThread::exec()`?Thanks!